# Usage of the verb "to drench" and the phrase "to be "

Tags: meaning

I found myself in difficulty explaining the difference between using the verb **drench** as in:

> 'I ***drenched*** the cake with lemon juice'

and

> 'I am ***drenched*** from the heavy rain'.

Is ***drenched*** in this phrase an adjective?

Comment: Yes. Many predicate adjectives are derived from verbal participles like this; often you can tell the difference by the preposition. _Tired of, wasted in, lost to, made of,_ etc.

Comment: Cakes are more commonly 'drizzled' with liquids, though that does not quite imply the same large amount of liquid as a drenching. But a modifier to 'drizzled' would more probably be used, i.e. 'heavily drizzled' if the amount of liquid was high. Or possibly 'soaked'.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

> "***drenched***" the cake"

you are performing an action on the cake.
So here, "***drench***" is a verb.

When you say

> "*I am **drenched***"

here ***drench*** is used to describe yourself- like *"drenched me"*.

So here, ***drench*** is an adjective.